FiguredBass with parentheses
I've been struggling with doing some \markups inside \figuremode because I would like to define some commands or functions to include all the boilerplate code inside.
For example, trying to put parentheses around some 'figure number, this code is working:
\version "2.20.0"
#(define-markup-command (parsis layout props strNumber) (string?)
   (interpret-markup layout props
                     (markup #:fontsize -2 (#:number (#:parenthesize strNumber)))))
<<
{\clef bass g2 g2}

\new FiguredBass {
  \figuremode {
    \bassFigureExtendersOn
    <7 \markup \parsis "6">2
    <7 5>2
  }
}
>>

The problem is I would like to call directly the command without the previous \markup, as:
<7 \parsis "6">2

But I have not succeeded. I tried to define some music-function or scheme-function which called \parsis, following the directions of these questions:
Modify markup with a scheme function
lily-scheme function to display a chord both as music and as markup
I even tried to follow the instructions given at Lilypond tutorial for Scheme:
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/extending/doubling-a-note-with-slurs-_0028example_0029
If anyone could give me some piece of advice I would be very grateful.
(Another less important question is I cannot call the argument as a number, but it works as a string).

Your code works with version 2.24, but you have to change the fontsize to -4 to get it to match with the other figures.

Another option is to just use square brackets, as seen in the documentation: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/figured-bass#entering-figured-bass

@ElementsInSpace Yes, the code works but I would like to include the \markup statement within a function or command to make the code cleaner and clearer. I am also already using the brackets for another purpose. Thank you.

You are creating a scheme command. This is not a regular function, but a special command used in \markup ... that is evaluated at a later point. Rather than doing that you want to create an actual function that returns a markup:
parsis =
#(define-scheme-function (strNumber) (string?)
   (markup #:fontsize -2 #:number #:parenthesize strNumber))

This allows you to do \parsis "6".
You will still find that \figuremode does not expect to resolve a function within <...>, which is why you’ll need to directly evaluate this function from scheme:
<<
{\clef bass g2 g2}

\new FiguredBass {
  \figuremode {
    \bassFigureExtendersOn
    <7 #(parsis "6")>2
    <7 5>2
  }
}
>>


Is there any way you can get the function to accept the number 6 (as apposed to "6")?

@ElementsInSpace Yes. Change the predicate string? to number? and use (number->string ...) instead. Or use the predicate scheme? and use (format #f "~a" ...) to allow everything and hope it works out.

Everything works perfectly, also with the numerical argument. I leave the code written explicitly for this last case: parsis = #(define-scheme-function (nNumber) (number?)    (markup #:fontsize -2 #:number #:parenthesize (number->string nNumber)))
